# 3.5.1 proportional editing objects can't keep last settings?

Tags: edit-mode

## Use the proportional editing objects:

[image]
[image]

I'm used to specifying the attenuation range before editing the object, but the new version can't do this anymore, is this intentional or a bug?

Comment: I can confirm that. Might be worth reporting as a bug via Blender's Help > Report a Bug menu.